# Assign a dynamic fragment of a string to a variable

Tags: php, rest, placeholder

I want to read and url and parse it, to pass a part of it as a parameter to a function.
Is there a way to create a sort of placeholder in a string?

This is the code:

```
switch ('localhost/documents/') {

    case 'img/{imageId}':
    $image = $controller->showDocumentImage($imageId);
    break;
}
```

Is there a way to do that? How can I take the number after the "img/" string and pass it to a function? It should be something like a restful simulation.

Comment: why you do switch('localhost/documents/') ? I don't get that... this code does nothing.

Comment: @kasperTaeymans I created a front controller which parses `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and splits it into different substring levels. The switch is used to instantiate different controllers, based on the url. E.g.: `localhost/appname/documents/requestedMethod` instantiate DocumentsController and starts the `requestedMethod()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your `switch` statement, doesn't make a lot of sense there.

You can use a [regular expression](https://www.php.net/preg_match) to extract the number after `img`:

```
if (preg_match('#img/(?P<imageId>\d+)#', 'img/123', $matches)) {
    // $matches['imageId'] == "123"
    $controller->showDocumentImage($matches['imageId']);
}
```

The actually regex you use may be different, depending on your needs.

Comment: What's the difference between your regex and this one: `(?<=img/).*(?=/)` ? I'm not used to regex.

Comment: The groups (parenthesis surrounded bits) are positive look behind and ahead assertions. My regex says: match `img/` followed by any number of digits. Yours says: Match anything (`.*`) that preceded by `img/` and followed by `/`.

Comment: Do you think this would be good? `(?<=img/)(?P<imgId>\d+)(?=/)` I don't know if I'm properly using the `?P<imgId>` part.

Comment: Sorry @chrisguitarguy , I've got a problem. My switch is needed because my code behaves differently depending on the string I'm reading. So I have to tell my code that in CASE the string I'm receiving is of this form `img/ID`, I've got to take the ID and use it as a variable elsewhere. That's why I need the switch. So how can I join regex and switch cases?